# Freezing Rails+Redcloth = Problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I've just frozen my Rails (2.3.2) application together with RedCloth (4.2.2) and deployed it to my shared hosting environment.

When running the application I get an error saying another version of RedCloth is already activated (4.2.2) when trying to load an older version.

I reckon this problem is because the hosting environment has an older version of RedCloth installed which Rails tries to activate in ActionView. **How do I get Rails to not activate the old RedCloth gem and instead use the newer version supplied with my application?**

I've already added the necessary config-code to my environment.rb-file (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedCloth has a native C extension. Is it built in the hosting environment?

Comment: I have no idea.. All I know is that a 'gem list' lists 'RedCloth (4.1.1, 3.0.4)'

Comment: Ok, that means it is not. Do a rake gems:build after you deploy your app on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping a local copy of that RedCloth version within your rails app in vendor/gems.

Comment: that would only work if you are deploying to the same system architecture.